# Error when installing Ubuntu for the first time

Tags: system-installation, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu for the 1st time.  First time installing any Linux program.

Have a brand new just ought of the box Thinkserver TS-140 with 2 - 1 TB drives configured as RAID 1.

I get to the part where I choose to *ERASE* any data and *install*...
I also choose to *install* updates...

I hit *enter* and immediately get **"ERROR ???"**, the rest of the **"error box"** just contain **"???"** so I don't even have clue as to what is wrong.

In the background is the "timezone Earth map" showing a default NY timezone and a *"continue"* button that does not work.

Help!!!!